# rollback function or design pattern in C++

Tags: c++

Right now, I am facing a new problem that I can't figure out how to fix. I have two files. One is a video file and other is a thumbnail. They have same name. I want to rename these two files using C++. I am using the `rename` function and it works. This is what I've written:

```
if(rename(videoFile) == 0)
{
     if(rename(thumbnail) != 0)
     {
         printf("Fail rename \n");
     }
}
```

The problem occurs when the video file is renamed successfully but for some reason the thumbnail can't be renamed. When this happens, I would like to rollback the renaming of the video file because the video file name and the thumbnail file name should be the same in my program. What I want to do is to rename after both files are okay to rename. Please guide me, any design pattern for function like rollback or third party software.

Comment: Unless the IO library you are using provides some feature for this, you are going to have to store the original file name and rename it back in case of failure. Of course, your renaming it back could also fail.. You could try to create blank files of the new names and then copy or move the old files into them if successful. This may be less likely to go wrong.

Comment: You can save the precious file name..if rename fails..you can again rename video file back to original

Comment: @Grv `you can again rename video file back to original` and if it fails?

Comment: @Grv and @ Servin yap i think like that before, but what happen if i fail again to rename video file after thumbnail is fail to rename. rename video file back to original could fail any time.

Comment: @Neil Kirk, That is not good. if file size is big, that deleting process may take a lot of time.

Comment: Usually the time to delete a file doesn't depend on its size.

Comment: @Neil Kirk... Yap, but I would like to mention in here is, user press delete button and if file size is big, I have to take some time to writing data in new files. right? before writing data to new file is not finish, I can't delete old file. For the users point of view, they will think deleting process is too long. That I would like to talk.

Comment: If you *move* a file to a place on the same harddisk, this usually completes in no time.

Comment: okay.... let's go back you first topic.... You said create new file, it still okay, then, I have 5 GB video file. Could you give me suggestion how to copy 5GD data to new create file using C++? you said  **completes in no time**. Could you write some codes that copy 5 GB data file to new created file within 1 second? What I knew is we have to read the data first from existing file and write that data to new file. That is kind of copy in C++.  even if you use  <copyfile.h> lib. you will have a delay time when copying file. I think you are misunderstanding my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no** absolutely foolproof way to do this.

Fundamental rule of disk I/O: The filesystem can change at any time.  You can't check whether a rename would succeed; your answer [is already wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOCTTOU).  You can't be certain that undoing the rename will succeed; somebody else might have taken the name while you briefly weren't using it.

On systems that support hard links, you can use them to get about 90% of the way there, assuming you're not moving between filesystems.  Suppose you're renaming A to B and C to D.  Then do these things:

1. Create hard link B which links to A.  This is written as `link("A", "B")` in C, using the Unix [`link(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/link) system call.  Windows users should call [`CreateHardLink()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.
2. If (1) succeeded, create hard link D which links to C.  Otherwise, return failure now.
3. If (2) succeeded, delete A and C and return success.  Otherwise, delete B and return failure.  If the deletions fail, there is no obvious means of recovery.  In practice, you can *probably* ignore failed deletions assuming the reason for failure was "file not found" or equivalent for your platform.

This is still vulnerable to race conditions if someone deletes one of the files out from under you at the wrong time, but that is arguably not an issue since it is largely equivalent to the rename failing (or succeeding) and *then* the person deleting the file afterwards.

Technically, you should also be opening the containing directory (in `O_RDONLY` mode) and [`fsync(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync)'ing it after each operation, at least under Unix.  If moving between directories, that's both the source and the destination directories.  In practice, *nobody* does this, particularly since it will lead to degraded performance under ext3.  Linus [takes the position](https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/3/25/632) that the filesystem ought to DTRT without this call, but it is formally required under POSIX.  As for Windows, I've been unable to find any authoritative reference on this issue on MSDN or elsewhere.  So far as I'm aware, Windows does not provide an API for synchronizing directory entries (you [can't `open()` a directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx#Anchor_2), so you can't get a file descriptor suitable to pass to `fsync()`).

**Nitpick**: To some extent, this sort of thing *can* be done perfectly on transactional filesystems, but just about the only one in common use right now is NTFS, and Microsoft [specifically tells developers not to use that feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If/when btrfs hits stable, transactions might become genuinely useful.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows platform starting from Vista, you can use code such as the following.

```
#include "KtmW32.h"

bool RenameFileTransact( LPCTSTR lpctszOldVideoFile, LPCTSTR  lpctszNewVideoFile, LPCTSTR lpctszOldThumbnailFile, LPCTSTR  lpctszNewThumbnailFile )
{
    bool bReturn = false;
    HANDLE hRnameTransaction = CreateTransaction(NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (MoveFileTransacted(lpctszOldVideoFile, lpctszNewVideoFile, NULL, NULL, 0, hRnameTransaction) &&
        MoveFileTransacted(lpctszOldThumbnailFile, lpctszNewThumbnailFile, NULL, NULL, 0, hRnameTransaction))
    {
        if ( CommitTransaction(hRnameTransaction))
        {
            bReturn = true;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle( hRnameTransaction );
    return bReturn;
}
```

But as @Kevin pointed out above, Microsoft discourages the usage of this good feature.

Comment: yap it could be. but I prefer pure C++ or third party lib that support to other platforms.